# How to access my local host server from internet

Tags: home-server, port-forwarding, wamp, dynamic-dns

**How to access my local host server from internet**
have installed WAMP server on my Windows XP, And i had created a index.php file in my root folder, and i assigned a virtual name to my localhost.
eg: earlier i accessed my index.php via:
Code:

http:// localhost/ index.php

but now i can access like :
Code:

http: //www. mysite. com/index.php

but the problem is that i can access this from my computer only..

how can i use it from internet.. please help me....

Thanks.

Comment: You need to ask this on superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

1. You need a static IP address from your Internet service provider. You also need to confirm they are not blocking inbound TCP port 80 if you want to be able to use http://www.mysite.com instead of a custom port like http://www.mysite.com:3490 (most ISPs do block this unless you pay for a higher-level service).
2. Enable port 80 (or whichever custom port you chose) on your firewall.
3. Configure and forward this port on your modem
4. Buy your domain name and assign it to your IP address